# Count days per month between two date ranges

Tags: date, hadoop

I'm calculating in Hadoop the number of days per month but my start and end dates cross months.
I.e. if the start column is 28th May and the end date is 3rd June then I need a result that shows the number of days in each month within that time window.

I.e.:

May 4

June 3

Hope that makes sense!

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I did not understand how you are calculating in Hadoop. Do you mean to say you are running a map reduce over some files in hdfs? How does the data in the file look like?

Comment: The table has 2 columns: Start date and End date.  I need to query the table so that I get the total number of days per month.  so if the start date is 28/05/2017 and the end date is 03/06/2017 then the result would group by month so the result would be may 4 and June 3 as there are 4 days in may and 3 days in june between the start and end date.